# CMB variance as percentage - does that make any sense?

Tags: cosmic-microwave-background, popular-science

Reading a popular science book that is pretty accurate and in depth, but stumbled upon this line (translated):

> The variation, that the CMB pattern reveals amounts to less than one hundredth of a percent.

I can’t figure out what that’s supposed to mean. What’s the reference magnitude here? Can’t be absolute temperature, that would be nonsensical. Can’t be referring to rms variance or anisotropy either, that’s completely different values.

Any idea? Or is it just badly worded?

Comment: *Can’t be absolute temperature, that would be nonsensical.* Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that the maximum amplitude of relative variations in the absolute temperature seen in different patches of the sky is about 1 part in ten thousand. This is frequently plotted in terms (roughly) of the square of the temperature fluctuations versus the angular scale of those fluctuations (see below).

[image: CMB power spectrum]

As to how exactly this ubiquitous picture of the CMB power spectrum translates into a rough temperature variation amplitude, I refer you to the as-yet unsatisfactorily (to me) answered question: [How to translate from the CMB Power spectrum to a spectrum of temperature variations](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/286521/how-to-translate-from-the-cmb-power-spectrum-to-a-spectrum-of-temperature-variat)

Edit: In fact forget the power spectrum, just look at the temperature map (minus the mean temperature) on the sky and note the variation compared to the mean value of 2.7K; about 0.01%. (Note though, this map has also taken out the dipole component due to our motion with respect to the CMB, which causes a larger, smooth variation).

[image: CMB T map]

Comment: Got it, thanks. That makes a little more sense. Thanks for the link to your question, I’ll have to wrap my head around that later.

Comment: I think the answer you had in that question is about as good as anyone can do. I did once look at the maths when I was an undergrad, but all I now remember is thinking it was brutal and I don't want to look at  it again!

Comment: The CMB power spectrum *is* the departure from *isotropy*. @CharlesFrancis

Comment: @RobJeffries, You are right.

Answer (score 2):

It is variation in temperature. Why would that not make sense?

Comment: Well my intuition was that absolute temperature and variation shouldn’t have anything to do with each other. Absolute temp. of the CMB obviously changes over time, whereas structure doesn’t. But I basically just wanted to know where the author pulled the number from to dig into it.

Comment: Homogeneity is an assumption. Perfect homogeneity cannot be expected. There should be random variations. This is to show that the random fluctuations are small on the scale at which we can measure them.

Comment: @lthz The variation in temperature we’re talking sbout is over *space*, not over *time*. It is anisotropy — slightly different temperatures in different directions.

Comment: They take the dipole anisotropy out (due to Earth's movement relative to CMB frame) before they calculate random fluctuations, which I think we are talking of here.

Comment: @CharlesFrancis Agreed.

Comment: Okay sorry, it still doesn’t make sense to me. Say we have 3K avg. and a spacial max variation of 3*10^-5K (1/10000). I would assume the average to be, say, 1K somewhere in the future because of redshift, but the variation to still be the same (and thus another percentage) because it isn’t time dependent. I get that angular scale of structure is linked to time since emission. Is that the point here? Feel free to ignore my confusion, if this is getting too dumb...

Comment: I think we are just talking about one point in the sky being a (very) little bit hotter or colder than another. I.e. there is a space variation, but as you say, there won't be a time variation.

Comment: @lthz Sorry, I don’t know how the anisotropy varies with time. That isn’t measurable, but I’m sure there is a prediction for it. I don’t see what it has to do with anything.

Comment: Okay last try: When I calculate percentage I assume that the relation of the whole 100% to the 1% or whatever has some meaning to it. In this case the *absolute* temperature of 3k, that is the 100%, is just an arbitrary snapshot and will be different tomorrow, whereas, as you agree, the variation is probably not. Meaning, that the percentage doesn’t tell us anything useful as opposed to, say, just the variation in Kelvin or the rms of the variation. Spatial or otherwise. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: The timescale for the expansion of the universe is so large that there is no chance of measuring a change from one millenia to the next, let alone tomorrow! The space variation tells us something about the assumption of homogeneity, which is fundamental to cosmology (although not to physics).

Comment: I do understand both of your points, of course we are interested in spatial variance and of course we can’t measure temporal changes. I only brought up time to demonstrate the fact that the *absolute* temperature bears no relation to the variance but obviously has an impact on the percentages. I’m obviously failing to communicate this to you, or I’m somehow failing to understand it. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: absolute temperature means temperature measured in Kelvin above absolute zero. It does not refer to the whole sky. That would be average temperature.

Comment: I know, but percentages only work in absolute terms. 2K and 4K is the same difference as 12K and 14K but not percentage wise. So giving the percentage assumes that the absolute values have some relationship to the differences.

Comment: @lthz, of course. The percentage variations are now as they were at the time of the CMB.